# POD is being terminated and created again due to scale up and it's running twice

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application that runs a code and at the end it sends an email with a report of the data. When I deploy pods on **GKE** , certain pods get terminated and a new pod is created due to Auto Scale, but the problem is that the termination is done after my code is finished and the email is sent twice for the same data.

Here is the **JSON** file of the deploy API:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
  "kind": "Job",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "$name",
    "namespace": "$namespace"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "********"
      },
      "spec": {
        "priorityClassName": "high-priority",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "******",
            "image": "$dockerScancatalogueImageRepo",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "env": $env,
            "resources": {
              "requests": {
                "memory": "2000Mi",
                "cpu": "2000m"
              },
              "limits":{
                  "memory":"2650Mi",
                  "cpu":"2650m"
              }            
             }
          }
        ],
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "docker-secret"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Never"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is a screen-shot of the pod events:

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you are affected by this "Note that even if you specify .spec.parallelism = 1 and .spec.completions = 1 and .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never", the same program may sometimes be started twice." from [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#handling-pod-and-container-failures). What happens if you increase terminationgraceperiodseconds in your yaml file?

Comment: @danyL I think your comment is very helpful, could you please help us posting it as an Answer instead of a Comment, for Community's benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that I had another jobs that deploy pods on my nodes with more priority , so it was trying to terminate my running pods but the job was already done and the email was already sent , so i fixed the problem by fixing the request and the limit resources on all my json files , i don't know if it's the perfect solution but for now it solved my problem.

Thank you all for you help

Answer (score 1):

"Perhaps you are affected by this "Note that even if you specify .spec.parallelism = 1 and .spec.completions = 1 and .spec.template.spec.restartPolicy = "Never", the same program may sometimes be started twice." from doc. What happens if you increase terminationgraceperiodseconds in your yaml file? – "

@danyL